# Xcode not displaying xcodeproj properly when opened from xcworkspace. Unable to edit build settings

Tags: ios, xcode

After updating Xcode it no longer displays the details of my xcodeproj files for my project or my pods. So I can no longer edit the configuration easily.
Opening the xcodeproj file on its own displays properly. I can't find this issue mentioned anywhere else. Any help would be appreciated:

The issue:

[image]

What it should look like:

[image]

I have tried restarting Xcode/computer. Problem still persists.
I checked the files for any git merge conflicts. There is none.